# Spring security 6: override token validation (jwk-set-uri specific)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I need to integrate spring security with the oidm identity provider.
The issue is that this idp has a GET type validation url that does not follow the standard.

https://xxxxx.domain/oauth2/rest/token/info?access_token=token

How can I override token validation in spring security 6 ?

Comment: what's 'token validation' to you ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a user-info endpoint, not an introspection endpoint.

To validate a JWT, you should be using a JWT decoder, this is much more efficient than token introspection.

To use user-info endpoint as introspection endpoint, you need to provide with your own [introspector bean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/6.1-SNAPSHOT/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/opaque-token.html#oauth2resourceserver-opaque-userinfo).